# Count values from array CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I have an array of float values, namely life, of which i want to count the number of entries with a value greater than 0 in CUDA.

On the CPU, the code would look like this:

```
int numParticles = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PARTICLES; i++){
    if(life[i]>0){
        numParticles++;
    }
}
```

Now in CUDA, I've tried something like this:

```
__global__ void update(float* life, int* numParticles){
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (life[idx]>0){
        (*numParticles)++;
    }
}
//life is a filled device pointer
int launchCount(float* life)
{
    int numParticles = 0;
    int* numParticles_d = 0;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&numParticles_d, sizeof(int));
    update<<<MAX_PARTICLES/THREADS_PER_BLOCK,THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(life, numParticles_d);
    cudaMemcpy(&numParticles, numParticles_d, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << "numParticles: " << numParticles << std::endl;
}
```

But for some reason the CUDA attempt always returns 0 for numParticles. How come?

Comment: Note also that your memory allocation code for `numParticles_d` is wrong and might also be causing problems at runtime

Comment: @talonmies how is the allocationcode wrong? how is it done correctly?

Comment: `numParticles_d` should be declared as a pointer to int, not an int. It might accidentally work if you are on a 32 bit system, so that `sizeof(int) = sizeof(*int)`, but in all likelihood it won't.

Comment: @talonmies Sorry, a typo. In my code, it was correct.

Comment: You haven't provide a complete example, so I can only go on what you posted. If you want a more definitive answer than the two you have already been provided with, you will need to edit an MCVE into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually launching `MAX_PARTICLES` threads, and multiple thread blocks are executing `(*numParticles)++;` concurrently. It is a race condition. So you have the result 0, or if you are luck, sometimes a little bigger than 0.

As your attempt to sum up `life[i]>0 ? 1 : 0` for all `i`, you could follow [CUDA parallel reduction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) to implement your kernel, or use [Thrust reduction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/#reductions) to simplify your life.

Comment: I've already thought about this, but since it ALWAYS returns 0, there seems to be another problem

Comment: @Dynamitos It depends on the probability of `life[i]>0`, and other things. Always 0 is also possible.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
if (life[idx]>0){
    (*numParticles)++;
}
```

is a read-after write hazard. Multiple threads will be simultaneously attempting to read and write from `numParticles`. The CUDA execution model does not guarantee anything about the order of simultaneous transactions.

You could make this work by using atomic memory transactions, for example:

```
if (life[idx]>0){
    atomicAdd(numParticles, 1);
}
```

This will serialize the memory transactions and make the calculation correct. It will also have a big negative effect on performance.

You might want to investigate having each block calculate a local sum using a reduction type calculation and then sum the block local sums atomically or on the host, or in a second kernel.